# How to select the last inserted ID on concatenated values

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the last inserted id of multiple inserted rows.

record_id is auto increment

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO records (record_id, user_id, status, x) values ";
         $varray = array();

        $rid = $row['record_id'];
        $uid =  $row['user_name'];
        $status =  $row['status'];
        $x =  $row['x'];

        $varray[] = "('$rid', '$uid', '$status', '$x')";

       $sql .= implode(',', $varray);

      mysql_query($sql); 

      $sql2 = "INSERT INTO status_logs (id, record_id, status_id, date, timestamp, notes, user_id, x) VALUES";

      $varray2[] = "(' ', mysql_insert_id(), '$status', '$uid', '$x')";

      $sql2 .= implode(',', $varray2);

       mysql_query($sql2);
```

This is the result:

```
INSERT INTO records (record_id, user_id,  notes, x) values ('', '1237615', 'this is a note', 'active')

INSERT INTO status_logs (log_id, record_id, status_id, date, timestamp, notes, user_id, x) VALUES('', INSERT INTO records (record_id, user_id,  notes, x) values ('', '1237615', 'this is a note', 'active')

INSERT INTO status_logs (log_id, record_id, status_id, date, timestamp, notes, user_id, x) VALUES('', mysql_insert_id(), '1', '2013:05:16 00:00:01', '', this is a note'', '1237615', 'active'), '1', '2013:05:16 00:00:01', '', this is a note'', '1237615', 'active')
```

There is no value for `mysql_insert_id()`.

Comment: You may want to read up a little bit about PDO which is a more secure way to insert data into your sql queries.

Comment: you could always do a query right after that selected the `MAX(id)`, it wouldnt be fool proof (possibly two submissions at the same time) but would at least be a start, alternatively accept the overhead of running separate queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing php function `mysql_insert_id()` and SQL `INSERT` statement syntax.

**Either** use MySQL function [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) in `VALUES` clause of `INSERT` statement

```sql
INSERT INTO records (user_id,  notes, x) VALUES('1237615', 'this is a note', 'active');
INSERT INTO status_logs (record_id, status_id, date, timestamp, notes, user_id, x)
VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(), '1', ...);
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**or** retrieve the last inserted id by making a separate call to `mysql_insert_id()` right after first `mysql_query()`. And then use that value when you as a parameter to your second query.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO records (user_id, ...) 
        VALUES(...)";
$result = mysql_query($sql); 
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()); //TODO beter error handling
}
$last_id = mysql_insert_id();
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO status_logs (record_id, ...) 
         VALUES $last_id, ...)";
$result = mysql_query($sql); 
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()); //TODO beter error handling
}
```

**Note:**

- You don't need to specify auto_incremented column in column list. Just omit it.
- Use at least some sort of error handling in your code

**On a side note**: Instead of interpolating query strings and leaving it wide open to sql-injections consider to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) with either `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I mis-reading your code, you're calling the PHP function `mysql_insert_id` from within the SQL?

What you need to do is grab that into a PHP variable first, then use the variable in the SQL. Something like this:

```
// Run the first query
 mysql_query($sql); 

// Grab the newly created record_id
$recordid= mysql_insert_id();
```

Then in the second INSERTs just use:

```
$varray2[] = "(' ', $recordid, '$status', '$uid', '$x')";
```